# pandas Calendar issue

Tags: python, pandas

This code for [CustomBusinessDay()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.CustomBusinessDay.html) works fine:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pandas.tseries.offsets import CustomBusinessDay

runday = datetime(2021,12,30).date()
nextday = (runday + CustomBusinessDay()).date()
```

output 1:

```
In [26]: nextday
Out[26]: datetime.date(2021, 12, 31)
```

However, when adding an optional calendar as in [date functionality](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html) , it produces the next business day even though today's date (Dec 31, 2021) is not a holiday according to a specified calendar below:

```
from pandas.tseries.holiday import AbstractHolidayCalendar, Holiday, \
    USMemorialDay,  USMartinLutherKingJr, USPresidentsDay, GoodFriday, \
    USLaborDay, USThanksgivingDay, nearest_workday


class NYSECalendar(AbstractHolidayCalendar):
    ''' NYSE holiday calendar via pandas '''
    rules = [
        Holiday('New Years Day', month=1, day=1, observance=nearest_workday),
        USMartinLutherKingJr,
        USPresidentsDay,
        GoodFriday,
        USMemorialDay,
        Holiday('USIndependenceDay', month=7, day=4, observance=nearest_workday),
        USLaborDay,
        USThanksgivingDay,
        Holiday('Christmas', month=12, day=25, observance=nearest_workday),
        ]
nextday = (runday + CustomBusinessDay(calendar=NYSECalendar())).date()
```

output2:

```
In [27]: nextday
Out[27]: datetime.date(2022, 1, 3)
```

Comment: For `output2`, what was the value of `runday`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is the location of your problem:

```py
Holiday('New Years Day', month=1, day=1, observance=nearest_workday)
```

If you take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/cea27b47b2b1ac804463e70d98443be3450688b0/pandas/tseries/holiday.py#L97), `nearest_workday` means that the holiday is observed on a Friday if it falls on a Saturday, and on a Monday if the holiday falls on a Sunday. Since New Year's Day 2022 falls on a Saturday, it is observed today (12/31/2021) according to your calendar.

Removing the `observance` parameter will lead to an output of `2021-12-31`.

Comment: thanks, replaced with [next_monday](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/cea27b47b2b1ac804463e70d98443be3450688b0/pandas/tseries/holiday.py#L37)